# evenBridge supported by cloudformation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to write a cloudformation template to send notification when there is a change in IAM settings.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-receive-alerts-when-your-iam-configuration-changes/

Is there a template for this already available?

Comment: We can do eventbridge rules in CF. Probably there is no ready made CF for it, but can translate all of the details in the blog into CF and deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Here is a template for this already available. So then  You can use the pattern from AWS Prescriptive Guidance1 to deploy an AWS CloudFormation template to receive notifications automatically when AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) settings are changed.

The template creates an Amazon CloudWatch Events event and an AWS Lambda function. The event uses AWS CloudTrail to monitor for any IAM configuration changes in the AWS account.

So then If a change is detected, the CloudWatch Events event initiates a Lambda function, which sends you an Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) notification informing you of the change event.

Please refer this as well as to get possible solution.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/send-a-notification-when-an-iam-user-is-created.html